# i-graph-python argument equivalent to pos in networkx

Tags: python-3.x, igraph, networkx

In networkx I am able to input the positions of node to be drawn using the second argument of

```
nx.draw(G, pos)
```

For instance I can do something like this:

```
    pos[sourceNode]=(x1,y1)
    pos[targetNode]=(x2,y2)
```

I know that i-graph has an argument layout, but I was not able to discover how to use it!

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right; in order to position the nodes yourself,  you need to use the `layout` argument to `plot`.  Here are some basic examples showing how to use the automatic layout functions and how to make your own.

First, let's make a simple graph as an example. I am setting the random seed so that my results will be reproducible.

```
from igraph import * 
import random

random.seed(123)
g = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(5, 0.5)
plot(g)
```

[image: First plot - no layout]

When you just plot like this,  you have no control of the layout.

There are a number of built-in functions to use specific algorithms for generating layouts.

```
LO = g.layout_kamada_kawai()
plot(g, layout=LO)
```

[image: Kamada-Kawai Layout]

But if you want to take complete control, you need to build your own layout. A layout is just a sequence of [x,y] pairs that say where to place the nodes. While x works the expected way,  the low y coordinates are at the top and the high y-values are at the bottom,  so you need to do a little transposition to set up your layout.

```
LO = [[0.0,1.0], [1.0,0.0], [1.0,1.0], [0.0,0.0], [0.5,-0.5]]
plot(g, layout=LO)
```

[image: Hand-crafted layout]